# AWS: Cloud Formation: Is it possible to use a list in "DependsOn" where only one needs to be done first

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a CF Template that runs a series of EMR steps. One of the middle steps depends on if this is a monthly report or a yearly report. So it uses a Condition, and if it's monthly the monthly step runs and if it's yearly the yearly step runs. For the final step, I would like to use DependsOn but say EITHER the monthly step or the yearly step ran previously - not both. Is such a thing possible? Maybe DependsOn isn't the best way to go about this?

Comment: Cloudformation allows you to use custom constructs. basically something thats backed by code running in lambda. So in theory you can do anything you want.

Comment: What is your template and how do you define monthly and yearly in it? As input paramters?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a state machine ?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I changed my monthly and final steps to use the same name - I didn't realize you could do that. So both final and monthly have a different condition which I set as a parameter in the lambda. Then the final step can use dependsOn since either monthly or final will have run. Hopefully that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Its **not possible**. You would have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to handle such a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I could edit my template to use the same name for both the Final and Monthly steps. So my lambda includes the parameter FinalMOR

```
{"ParameterKey": "FinalMOR", "ParameterValue": "true"}
```

and my template looks like

```
"pysparkStep1": {"Type": "AWS::EMR::Step", "Properties": ... "Args": [step1prog]...
"pysparkStep2": {"Type": "AWS::EMR::Step", "Condition": "MonthlyMOR",
        "DependsOn": ["pysparkStep1"], "Properties": ... "Args": [step2Monthlyprog]...
"pysparkStep2": {"Type": "AWS::EMR::Step", "Condition": "FinalMOR",
        "DependsOn": ["pysparkStep1"], "Properties": ... "Args": [step2Finalprog]...
"pysparkStep3": {"Type": "AWS::EMR::Step", "DependsOn": ["pysparkStep2"],
    "Properties": ... "Args": [step3prog]...
```